# Efficient way to store a list of pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have around 500-1500 dataframes to store in-memory since we manipulate
the pandas dataframe for computation.

Dont want to use HDF5 since this disk writing (we want to keep in memory).
What is the most efficient storage in Python of dataframe ?

1) List but it seems memory heavy after 500 dataframes
2) NUmpy object array ?
3) Tuples ?

**ANSWER:**

As nobody was able to put a practical answer to this (ONLY NEGATIVE items from People without any comments...)? I put the best solution I have found so far:

**It seems that blist package has better performance than the current list
for operations on list. I tested it and now works well.**

Here are some of the use cases where the blist asymptotically outperforms the built-in list:

```
Use Case                                       blist            list
Insertion into or removal from a list          O(log n)         O(n)
Taking slices of lists                         O(log n)         O(n)
Making shallow copies of lists                 O(1)             O(n)
Changing slices of lists                       O(log n + log k) O(n+k)
Multiplying a list to make a sparse list       O(log k)         O(kn)
Maintain a sorted lists with bisect.insort     O(log**2 n)      O(n)
```

Reference 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/

Comment: Why this question is "negative" ?
What is the purpose of putting this question negative withou any comments ?

is StackOver Flows rules for members to put systematically negative for newcomers ?

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to achieve. There might be quite different answers depending on your tasks, on the data/DF structures, etc. For example if all your DFs are of the same shape you could use Panel or xarray. You could use dict of DFs instead of a list. Depending on your goals you could even merge all of them into one DF and add a new column identifying each source DF. There is no good common, abstract, generic answer for  such a broad question, IMO

Comment: Thank you, this is a  good comment better than putting systematic negative to the question.

I think there is a kind of habits to put "NEGATIVE" to all new-comers questions, so StackOverflows people enjoys it....

Answer (score 1):

Since your data frame is **already** stored in memory, it doesn't matter in which object you'll embedded it in, it will always take at least the amount of ram required for all of them.

One useful feature of the data frame is memory_usage which let you know how much ram a given data frame is taking. It will make you wonder if you really want to store double precision float when you don't need the precision.

Comment: Am talking about the overhard of list.
it seems list has some overhard compared to others

Answer (score 1):

It seems that blist package has better performance than the current list
for operations on list. I tested it and now works well.

Here are some of the use cases where the blist asymptotically outperforms the built-in list:

```
Use Case                                       blist            list
Insertion into or removal from a list          O(log n)         O(n)
Taking slices of lists                         O(log n)         O(n)
Making shallow copies of lists                 O(1)             O(n)
Changing slices of lists                       O(log n + log k) O(n+k)
Multiplying a list to make a sparse list       O(log k)         O(kn)
Maintain a sorted lists with bisect.insort     O(log**2 n)      O(n)
```

Reference 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/